# Image to pop up in front another image in 3D while hovering

Tags: css

Here is a fiddle to demonstrate my question
*[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vhvet)*

**CSS:**

```
#email { 
list-style: none; 
   margin: 100px 0; 
   height: 550px; 
}
#email li { 
   display: inline; 
   float: left;
   -webkit-perspective: 500; 
   -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
   -webkit-transition-property: perspective; 
   -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
   -moz-perspective: 500; 
   -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
   -moz-transition-property: perspective; 
   -moz-transition-duration: 0.5s; 
}
#email li:hover {
   -webkit-perspective: 5000; 
   -moz-perspective: 5000;
}
#email li div { 
   border: 10px solid #fcfafa; 
   -webkit-transform: rotateY(30deg);
   -moz-transform: rotateY(30deg);
   -moz-box-shadow:0 3px 10px #888; 
   -webkit-box-shadow:0 3px 10px #888;
   -webkit-transition-property: transform; 
   -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s; 
   -moz-transition-property: transform; 
   -moz-transition-duration: 0.5s; 
}
#email li:hover div { 
   -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg); 
   -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="email">
    <li>
       <div style="width: 180px; height: 180px; margin-bottom: 10px; background-color:green"><div>
       <div style="width: 250px; height: 200px; margin-left: 5px; margin-bottom: 10px; background-color: red"></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

As you can see in the fiddle, I have used two different div elements in **3D**: one in front and the other behind it.

Now when I hover over the div, the position changes. While hovering, I need the div with the green colour to align in front of the div with the red colour.

I am new to CSS, so looking for any help.
Thanks

Comment: here is the fiddle guys  http://jsfiddle.net/vhvet/

Comment: i have given the jsfiddle also waiting for ur help friends....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made another modification.  It turns out that Chrome needs a transform on the non-hovered element in order to position it while hovering.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jjordanca/NYpbS/2/

**HTML**

```
<ul id="email">
    <li>
        <div class="green" style="width:180px;height:180px;background-color:green"></div>
        <div class="red" style="width:250px;height:200px;margin-left:5px;background-color:red"></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
#email {
    list-style:none;
    margin:100px 0;
    height:550px;
}

#email li{
    display: block;
    -webkit-perspective: 500px;
    -moz-perspective: 500px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -moz-transform-origin: 25% 50%;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 25% 50%;
}

#email:hover .green {
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(100px,0,175px);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(100px,0,175px);
    -webkit-transition-property: transform;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
    -moz-transition-property: transform;
    -moz-transition-duration: 1s;
    z-index: 2;
}

#email:hover .red {
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, -175px);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, -175px);
    -webkit-transition-property: transform;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
    -moz-transition-property: transform;
    -moz-transition-duration: 1s;
    z-index: 1;
}

#email li div {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    -moz-box-shadow:0 3px 10px #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 3px 10px #888;
}

#email li .green {
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(50px, -50px, -50px);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(50px, -50px, -50px);
    z-index: 1;
}

#email li .red {
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(150px, 50px, 50px);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(150px, 50px, 50px);
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you're looking for a flip animation or a different kind of animation, but I don't have enough reputation to ask you to clarify.

I've created a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/jjordanca/dUbpN/

It uses roughly the same parameters as you've given in your HTML and CSS.  Note that we've moved the perspective to be in the `#email`, and that the transformation is taking place on the actual object, the `li`.  I've added the `.green` and `.red` classes to make it easier to read the CSS, but this can easily be done using child and sibling selectors if you're not able or willing to add more classes.

**HTML**

```
<ul id="email">
    <li>
        <div class="green" style="width:180px;height:180px;margin-bottom:10px;background-color:green"></div>
        <div class="red" style="width:250px;height:200px;margin-left:5px;margin-bottom:10px;background-color:red"></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
#email {
    list-style:none;
    margin:100px 0;
    height:550px;
    -webkit-perspective: 500;
    -moz-perspective: 500;
    position: relative;
}

#email li{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transition-property: transform;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transition-property: transform;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -moz-transform-origin: 25% 50%;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 25% 50%;
}

#email:hover li {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -webkit-transition-property: transform;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
    -moz-transition-property: transform;
    -moz-transition-duration: 1s;
}

#email li div {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    -moz-box-shadow:0 3px 10px #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 3px 10px #888;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

#email li div.red {
 z-index: 2;   
}

#email li div.green {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

Comment: thanks for ur answer @xaxio , but i am looking for something else, that is using twom images one above the other and want to bring the back image to front while hovering.....

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is more what you're looking for, then?  I'm leaving my existing answer alone so the comments to it don't get confusing.

Another jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jjordanca/NYpbS/

**HTML**

```
<ul id="email">
    <li>
        <div class="green" style="width:180px;height:180px;background-color:green"></div>
        <div class="red" style="width:250px;height:200px;margin-left:5px;background-color:red"></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
#email {
    list-style:none;
    margin:100px 0;
    height:550px;
}

#email li{
    display: block;
    -webkit-perspective: 500px;
    -moz-perspective: 500px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -moz-transform-origin: 25% 50%;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 25% 50%;
}

#email:hover li .green {
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(50px);
    -moz-transform: translateZ(50px);
    -webkit-transition-property: transform;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
    -moz-transition-property: transform;
    -moz-transition-duration: 1s;
}

#email:hover li .red {
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(-50px);
    -moz-transform: translateZ(-50px);
    -webkit-transition-property: transform;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
    -moz-transition-property: transform;
    -moz-transition-duration: 1s;
}

#email li div {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    -moz-box-shadow:0 3px 10px #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 3px 10px #888;
}

#email li .green {
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100px, -100px, -100px);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(-100px, -100px, -100px);
}
```

Comment: thanks @xaxio..you are almost there..but still my question is...i want the green box to come front of red one while hovering..i think u can understand what i am asking now..i just want the grren one displayed in front of red one while hovering...

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what it is that you're looking for.  Are you saying that you want the red one to disappear completely such that only the green one shows while the mouse is over it?

Comment: no i want the red one to move back and the green one to come front while hovering..